# Should every tag have a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I noticed that the tag [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) does not have a tag wiki, but [logical-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-operators) does. I was about to set about writing one, but first I checked out some tag wiki writing advice, since it would be my first tag-wiki. The advice left me with some doubt about whether [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) needed a wiki at all.

Specifically, addressing points from [Jeff's blog post about tag-wikis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)

> 2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is
>      highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does not need to
>      explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet
>      users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate
>      explanation of email to anyone.

"Relational operator" is vocabulary known by a smaller audience than "email", but I would expect most programmers to know what a relational operator is.

> 3. Concentrate on what a tag means to your community. For “email” on
>      Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3,
>      SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention
>      desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would be
>      more appropriate for webapps.stackexchange.com.

Um, I think relational operator has a very specific meaning, so I'm not sure how it would have a different meaning to our community than elsewhere.

> 4. Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag. In other words, what
>      kinds of questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of
>      organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which
>      questions need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the
>      tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags
>      screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select
>      your tag?

Looking at existing questions tagged with [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators), it looks like users should use this tag when they have questions about the usage of relational operators, so not much to explain here either.

> 5. Some tags are common knowledge. Most tags require a bit of explanation
>      in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if the tag is
>      common knowledge — that is, if you walked up to any random person on
>      the street and said the tag word to them, and they would know what you
>      were talking about — then don’t bother explaining the tag at all.
>      Stick to usage of the tag within your community in the excerpt.

I wouldn't expect a person on the street without programming experience to know what a relational operator is, which suggests that I should provide a basic definition, contradicting point 2. This leaves the decision on whether or not [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) should have a wiki to a judgement on how many people understand the definition.

However, the advice seems clear that if a tag's definition is unambiguous, universally known, and no additional guidance on usage is required there's not much left to add to the tag wiki. In that case, should tag wikis/excerpts be left empty?

To be clear, I am asking about tags in general; I only use [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) as an example.

Comment: IMHO the tag wiki should not become another Wikipedia. However, it should contain important information to decide whether a question should be tagged with a particular tag or not.

Comment: @Melebius there is a distinction between tag-wiki **info** and tag-wiki **excerpt**. The later is for the usage/guidance, but the former is fine for a definition (think Wiktionary instead of Wikipedia) and sourcing documentation and resources.

Comment: actually what's email?

Comment: And yet, `[email]` has a tag wiki _explaining precisely that_.

Comment: Yes, every tag should have a tag wiki, most already do.

Comment: A brief summary is always needed I think. And the example of email's tag  is plainly bad, yes we all knows what an email is, however how the system based on the email work (mail domain, smtp, rfc, ....) is a whole another matter. Furthermore some part about mails aren't on-topic on SO. I think that the email wiki is in fact a very good example of what it should be : explain some basic concepts and what kind of question about this tag are welcomed here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**If there's no other necessary info to convey, I don't see any harm in a brief description.**

I've always thought of the tag excerpt as a way to quickly understand a tag, even if I'm not particularly familiar with the term.

As silly as it sounds, before reading this post I did not know what a relational operator was. I didn't know there was a standardized term for these types of operators.

In this case, a possible excerpt for [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) would be:

> Questions about operators that test the relationship between two objects/variables/entities. These can apply to operators in any language.

---

Since people seemed to like my suggestion, I went ahead and suggested an edit to the tag excerpt.

[image: About relational operators]

Comment: You'd probably not learn this from SO even if there was a tag wiki, because that means that you must know that the tag exists in order to learn. That's not how SO works though. Suppose you post a question about the "lesser-than" operator in some programming language and think you should tag your question. You start to type "lesser" in the tag window and find that there is no such tag. Realization: this is not a formal term. Quick google for "lesser than operator" gives relational operators as hit number 3, Wikipedia. Aha. You add this as the tag. All good - you made your question better.

Answer (score 0):

SO is a community of programmers, so let's post wikis that summarize a definition [such as Wikipedia's in this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator) in the context of programming. That might discourage, for example, the use 
 of [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators) on the operators of the relational algebra, such as `join`, `project` and `restrict`.

In this particular case, I would suggest that the excerpt encourage the tag for questions about relational operators in general, like 'Do all the relational operators in language x have equal precedence?' or 'How does parser Y represent relational operators in the AST?'.  I think that a question about one or a few operators, like [What is the equivalent of “!=” in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595757/what-is-the-equivalent-of-in-excel-vba), is right to omit this tag in favour of more specific tags, such as [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality), [inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inequality) and [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparison).

Comment: The exact term _relational operators_ is used by many programming language standards as the formal name for this group of operators. As such it would be the most correct term to use in programming discussions about these operators. So the tag fills a purpose and we shouldn't discourage using it. (In which case we could as well quickly burn it, given the few questions tagged with it.)

Comment: @Lundin good point. I would say: encourage it for questions like 'Do all the relational operators in language x have equal precedence?' or 'How does parser Y represent relational operators in the AST?', but not for [What is the equivalent of “!=” in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595757/what-is-the-equivalent-of-in-excel-vba) Feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score -4):

This particular case probably doesn't need a tag wiki. Because... what good would it do?

These operators exist in pretty much every programming language, but they do not necessarily have the same syntax from language to language. It would have to be a very generic post, perhaps with a few examples from certain programming languages.

The tag is overall mildly useful on its own, because of the broad scope. Nobody comes looking for "generic relational operator questions". But it can be used for categorizing questions, when used together with a programming language. For example

[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [relational-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-operators)

If you would insist on writing a tag wiki, this would be something you'd want to point out. "This tag should always be used together with a programming language tag." It may be all the tag usage guidance needed.

Looking at [logical-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/logical-operators/info), the tag wiki is pretty awful. It assumes that a C-like language is used by making a specific example. It adds a list of operations that should be common knowledge to anyone who has studied a bare minimum of computer science. It adds nothing of value neither to SO nor the reader and is a good example of a tag wiki we could as well do without.

Comment: "This tag should always be used together with a programming language tag". Then it is a meta-tag.

Comment: Uh, no. That doesn't make it a meta tag. If it did, every tag *but* the programming language tags would be meta tags. A meta tag is one that describes not the *contents* of the question, but rather its *nature*, like [homework].

Comment: @S.L.Barth No, a meta tag is something such as [C++-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). Relational operators is a programming language feature. And needless to say, the various features of programming languages doesn't make much sense by their own. For example you would never ask a questions about "functions in programming languages" (it would also be too broad for this site), but rather a question about functions in Java.

Comment: Well, I checked [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and Cody Gray is right. I stand corrected. That blog post that defined meta-tags also pointed out, though, that if the tag couldn't exist on its own, it was _probably_ a meta-tag. Turns out that what we have here is a _dependent_ tag that is not a meta-tag - a counterexample to the (somewhat implicit) statement in the article that meta-tags are a subset of dependent tags.